# Use of undefined constant category/Illegal string offset

Tags: php, apache

So I'm trying to build a dynamic dropdown for a website in PHP, from an array of categories from my database, and it was working  and I'm getting 7 errors of the exact type (7 is the amount of categories I have). Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$categories = getCategories();

$catList = '<select name="categoryId" id="categoryId">';
$catList .= '<option>Choose a Category</option>';

  foreach ($categories as $category){
    $catList .= "<option value='$category[categoryId]'"; 
      if(isset($categoryId)){
        if(category['categoryId'] === "$categoryId"){
          $catList .= ' selected ';
        } 
      }
    $catList .= ">$category[categoryName]</option>";
    }
$catList .= "</select>";
?>
```

And here are the error messages:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant category - assumed 'category' in 
C:\my\path\to\the\addproduct.php on line 8

Warning: Illegal string offset 'categoryId' in 
C:\my\path\to\the\addproduct.php on line 8
```

For reference, line 8 is `if(category['categoryId'] === $categoryId){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on line 8. you forgot to add the `$` before category. Remember it is a php variable.  Change it to the below

```
   if($category['categoryId'] === "$categoryId"){
```

Comment: Thank you so much for catching my typo...I'll accept it as soon as I can (10 minutes!!) Thank you! :)

Comment: my pleasure @AdamMcGurk

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(category['categoryId'] === "$categoryId"){
```

to

```
if($category['categoryId'] === "$categoryId"){
```

Comment: Thanks so much...I wish I could accept both answers, but he answered like 30 seconds before you haha...typos like this happen when you stare at code for four hours I guess...thank you!